# How to convert Arraylist consisting of pojo class into array in java

Tags: java, android

I have a pojo class named "Performance" like this

```
public class Performance {

    String productId;
    String productBrand;
    String productGraph;
    //getters and setters
```

And I saved it to arraylist named "performanceList" like this:

```
JSONArray dataGraph=null;
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
dataGraph = obj.getJSONArray("product_list");

performanceList.clear();
for(int i=0;i<dataGraph.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = dataGraph.getJSONObject(i);

    Performance performance = new Performance();
    if(!jsonObject.isNull("id")){
        performance.setProductId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
    }
    if(!jsonObject.isNull("brand")) {
        performance.setProductBrand(jsonObject.getString("brand"));
    }
    if(!jsonObject.isNull("sales")){
        performance.setProductGraph(jsonObject.getString("sales"));
    }
    performanceList.add(i, performance);
}
```

And now, can you please help me fetch the data from arraylist and be converted into array just like this

```
String []brand = {/*getProductBrand from arraylist*/};
String []id = {/*getProductId from arraylist*/};
String []id = {/*getProductGraph from arraylist*/};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach or for loop

```
String[] brand = new String[performanceList.size()];


for(int i=0;i<performanceList.size();i++)
{

brand[i] = performanceList.get(i).getBrand();
.....
......
}
```

Similary for other fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could use stream.map() in java8

```
List<String> productBrands = performanceList
                .stream()
                .map(el-> el.getProductBrand())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

repeat same for el.getId() or any other data you need to collect from Performance objects

Comment: OP wants to retrieve an array, therefore you can do this `String []brand = performances.stream().map(Performance::getProductBrand).toArray(String[]::new);`